# How to use tnsnames.ora and a client wallet in node using Typeorm?

Tags: node.js, oracle, typeorm, node-oracledb

I'm trying to connect to an external Oracle DB using TNS and a client wallet. My organization mandates that exact set up, so I have no way around. The problem is that I'm a complete noob when it comes to Oracle and the internet just doesn't have information for complete zeros - it implies some knowledge. node-oracledb itself doesn't have very descriptive error messages, so I'm just kind of hung out to dry here, I'd appreciate any guidance.

Here's my setup:

```
// This is the TypeORM config

{
  type: 'oracle',
  connectString: 'org',
  username: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASS,
}



// .bashrc sets the env variable to the config dir

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/oracle/instantclient
export TNS_ADMIN=/opt/oracle



// tnsnames.ora

org =
        (DESCRIPTION =
                (ADDRESS =
                        (PROTOCOL = TCPS)
                        (HOST = prac-scan.it.org.com)
                        (PORT = 1533)
                )
                (CONNECT_DATA =
                        (FAILOVER_MODE =
                                (TYPE = select)
                                (METHOD = basic)
                                (RETRIES = 180)
                                (DELAY = 5)
                        )
                        (SERVICE_NAME = DB.ORG.COM)
                )
        )

// sqlnet.ora

WALLET_LOCATION = (SOURCE =
        (METHOD = FILE)
        (METHOD_DATA =
                (DIRECTORY=/opt/oracle)
        )
)
```

What I get like this is

```
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

If I move the string from tnsnames.ora directly into the config in JS, I get this error:

```
ORA-28759: failure to open file
```

So here I am, no idea what I'm doing. Not even sure how to debug, it's just not a popular thing to mix node and oracle, it seems. I'll appreciate any direction.

UPD: found that I can put the wallet directory definition right with the string, so my TypeORM config became:

```
{
  connectString: `(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCPS)(HOST=prac-scan.it.org.com)(PORT=1533))(CONNECT_DATA=(FAILOVER_MODE=(TYPE=select)(METHOD=basic)(RETRIES=180)(DELAY=5))(SERVICE_NAME=DB.ORG.COM))(SECURITY=(MY_WALLET_DIRECTORY=/opt/oracle)))`,
}
```

So the error I get now is:

```
ORA-28864: SSL connection closed gracefully
```

Comment: You look like you're on the right track.  However I suggest you ask your DBA for what configuration they suggest - are you sure you don't need other settings in sqlnet.ora?  To keep it simple, use SQL\*Plus (not SQL Developer etc) and get that connecting.  Then use the same env vars and credentials in your Node app.  Some references: https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/09/ora-12545-12541-12514-01017/ and https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/post/how-to-connect-to-oracle-autonomous-cloud-databases

Comment: @christopher-jones thanks, that helps, I didn't think of trying SQL*Plus. My DBA unfortunately decided to do the upgrade without scheduling any time for support, so that's fun  I'll check the references you gave here, thanks again!

Comment: The ORA-12154 meant your tnsnames.ora file wasn't found.  Was it really in `/opt/oracle`?   Either put the tnsnames.ora & sqlnet.ora files in `/opt/oracle/instantclient/network/admin/` and don't set TNS_ADMIN.  Or perhaps use `initOracleClient({configDir: '/dir/containing/the/file'});` to avoid any issues with TNS_ADMIN not being passed through to the Node.js process.

Comment: @christopher-jones You're right, I was pretty close! I tried setting it up while logging in with SQL*Plus, got it working, but not the node app. Then I found that PM2 caches env variables, so I just had to tell it to refresh that and we're up and running! Thanks for your help

Comment: I'm glad you solved it.